# Long polynomial division with two variables $\frac{x^4-4a^3x+3a^4}{x-a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to show that $x-a$ is a factor of $x^4-4a^3x+3a^4$. I've tried long polynomial division but stopped in the middle of it as it didn't seem to work. How else could one approach it?

Comment: To show that $x-a$ is a factor you only have to show that $x^{4}-4a^{3}x+3a^{4}=0$ when $x=a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use long division, don't forget those missing terms.

Think about the place-holder $0$ as in $1\color{red}{0}3$.

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
    & & & x^3 & +ax^2 & +a^2 x & -3a^3 \\
    & & -- & --- & --- & --- & --- \\
   x-a & ) & x^4  & \color{red}{+0x^3} & \color{red}{+0x^2} & -4a^3x & +3a^4 \\
    & & x^4 & -ax^3    \\
    & & -- & --- & --- \\
    & & & ax^3 \\
    & & & ax^3 & -a^2x^2 \\
    & & & --- & --- & --- \\
    & & & & a^2x^2 & -4a^3x \\
    & & & & a^2x^2 & -a^2x & \\
    & & & & --- & --- & --- \\
    & & & & & -3a^3x & +3a^4 \\
    & & & & & -3a^3x  & +3a^4 \\
    & & & & & --- & ---
\end{array}

Comment: That's helped, thank you. There's a typo in the quotient, should be $x^3+ax^2+a^2x-3a^3$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
If polynomial division is asked for, following is how it can be factorised. Otherwise proving that $x-a$ is a factor is a trivial application of the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem). $$x^4-4a^3x+3a^4=(x^4-ax^3)+(ax^3-a^2x^2)+(a^2x^2-a^3x)+(-3a^3x+3a^4)$$

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the expression by $a^4$ you obtain

$(x/a)^4-4x/a+3=(x/a)^4-4x/a+4-1=(x/a-2)^2-1$

Now, using the fact that $t^2-1=(t+1)(t-1)$ yelds to

$(x/a-2)^2-1=(x/a-1)(x/a-3)=1/a^2(x-a)(x-3a)$

obtaining what you are asking for.