# Division of Polynomials with Division Statement

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

The question is as follows: Divide the following Polynomial and place the result into Division Statement.

$$\frac{m^4+n^4}{m^2+n^2}$$

Recently did this on a test and was stumped. A few calulators and classmates later, I'm still stumped.

I know that the division statement is $P(x) = q(x)*d(x) + R$. And I know that the remainder is going to be zero, or 1 degree less than the divisor. In this case, that means a linear remainder.

Trying to use long division did not work, and synthetic division is not possible. Without dividing, I can write the following, just given the information at hand.

$$m^4+n^4=q(x) *(m^2+n^2)+R$$

Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: Also, what's the variable:  $m$ or $n$?

Comment: They're both the variables, the question has two of them.

Comment: Unless I'm way off, there is no such thing as a division algorithm for polynomials in two variables.

Comment: The only thing I could think of was if the top and bottom are factorable, you could factor them and divide that way. This is why I was so stumped on this question, because far as I know there isn't either.

Comment: I can think of another reason (which happens from time to time). The actual division rather concerns  $$\frac{m^4-n^4}{m^2+n^2}$$

Comment: That would point to a typo on the test, because of course a difference of quartics is easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like $$m^4+n^4=(m^2-n^2)(m^2+n^2)+2n^4?$$

That's what you get if you just do long division of $m^2+n^2$ into $m^4+n^4$: you get a quotient of $m^2-n^2$ and a remainder of $2n^4$

$$\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}\color{red}{m^2}\color{green}{-n^2}\\[-3pt]
m^2+n^2\enclose{longdiv}{m^4+n^4}\\[-3pt]
\underline{\color{red}{m^4+m^2n^2}}\\[-3pt]
-m^2n^2+n^4 \\[-3pt]
\underline{\color{green}{-m^2n^2-n^4}}\\[-3pt]
2n^4\end{array}$$

[someone might know how to edit this so it looks better!]

Comment: What was your process for long division? The answer is definitely right, but, how?

Comment: Treat $m$ as a variable and $n$ as a constant. (The polynomial is treated as being in $m$ rather than in $x$.)

However, I find a fault with the problem statement: they should've told you that $m$ is the variable! You would get a different result if $n$ was the variable. Or if $x$ was the variable - in which case this is just a division of two constants, so it is its own quotient and the remainder is $0$...)

Comment: @IsaacK please see my edited answer

Comment: Solid. I hope you didn't spent 20 minutes writing that out XD. Thanks :)

Comment: I think this works perfectly if only $m$ is a variable.  Else, the condition on the degree of the remainder fails.

Comment: May see also my clumsy version of long division [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3950987/long-polynomial-division-with-two-variables-fracx4-4a3x3a4x-a/3951018#3951018) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889933/finding-square-root/1890078#1890078).

Answer (score 1):

With the concept of **homogeneous polynomials**, insert the missing terms:

$$\frac{m^4
\color{red}{+0} \color{blue}{m^3 n}
\color{red}{+0} \color{blue}{m^2 n^2}
\color{red}{+0} \color{blue}{mn^3}+
n^4}{m^2
\color{red}{+0} \color{blue}{mn}+
n^2}$$

then do the long division.

For economy, by letting $(a,b)=(m^2,n^2)$, we may skip those odd terms (of $m$ and $n$):

$$\frac{a^2
\color{red}{+0} \color{blue}{ab}+
b^2}{a+b}=
\frac{m^4
\color{red}{+0} \color{blue}{m^2 n^2}+
n^4}{m^2+n^2}$$